# Jquery, trying to move a div that is position absolute in all webbrowsers

Tags: jquery, animation, html, button, move

I have programming a bit on a website while i wanted to move a div that is position absolute. My jQuery code is like this:

```
var start = 0;

function myFunction(){
            switch(start){
                case 0:

                    $(live_embed_player_flash).width(960);
                    $(live_embed_player_flash).height(585);
                    $(button1).animate({"left": "+=330px"}, 770);
                    $(chat_embed).delay(800).hide();
                    $(button1).css("background-image", "url(img/15.png)");
                    button1.title = 'Show chat';
                    start=1;
                    break;

                case 1:

                    $(live_embed_player_flash).width(630);
                    $(live_embed_player_flash).height(400);
                    $(button1).css({"left": "-=330px"}, 740);
                    $(chat_embed).delay(800).fadeIn(1500);
                    $(button1).css("background-image", "url(img/16.png)");
                    button1.title = 'Hide chat';
                    start=0;
                    break;

            }
        }
```

What I am trying to do is to re-size one dive and move another div at the same time.

This code worked perfectly until my friend tested it on chrome. Thinks started to get weird and the problem is when I try to move the button div with:

```
$(button1).animate({"left": "+=330px"}, 770);
```

This is the site i am working on (the button over the stream is the button that's move and stuff)

http://berzanlabb.se/te11e/robrot060/SlutProjekt1/index.html

Comment: have you tried using instead: "left": "+=330"  without specifying unit

Comment: It doesn't help i still get the same error in chrome